# Kscript: script compilation failed. What's the issue?

Tags: kotlin, scripting, kotlin-script

I can't execute a simple Kotlin script because of compilation failed due to an invalid argument.

This is my Kotlin script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript 
println("Helloooo")
```

Then I've writter my very simple script, I've add executable permission to execute it:
`chmod u+x SomeScript.kts`

This is the error:

```
$ ./SomeScript.kts
[kscript] [ERROR] compilation of './SomeScript.kts' failed
error: invalid argument: -d
info: use -help for more information
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Solved! I had already properly installed kscript via Homebrew, but, for some reason, only `kotlinc` was out of the PATH. I added it, and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Have you install right kscript?
Check here https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript in base your system OS